Calculating the first digits of $9^{9^9}$
Long ago I told my fellow, a maths student, the following conundrum: What is the largest number you can write down with three digits? Well, the joke is, it's not 999, it's $9^{9^9}$. That is $9^{\left(9^9\right)}$ = $9^{387,420,489}$. This is a "very large" number and cannot be computed right away.
My fellow, though, took a regular calculator, typed something in and then showed me the first eight digits of that number. It showed the result of a calculation in a form 1.2345678 E90, but only the digits as such did matter. How did he do that?

I'm not quite sure what you're asking here. The title suggests you're interested in the most significant digits of $9^{9^9}$, but then you ask about a different calculation (the number 1.2345678 E90 is far smaller than $9^{9^9}$).

Or you could use $9[9]9$, which is much bigger. Your number is only $9[4]3$. (If you allow hexadecimal digits, the far bigger $F[F]F$ is possible.)

I wouldn't trust any of the digits a calculator shows when it gives up.

The given number is not the result of the calculation, but as stated, was provided in such a form

You can mix math knowledge and a calculator. You want to compute $9^{(9^9)}$.
The calculator immediately says $9^9=387420489$.
So you want $9^{387420489}$, which is $10^{387420489\times log_{10}(9)}$.
The calculator would tell you $387420489\times log_{10}(9)$ is close to $369693099.63157034$
The number you want is then close to $10^{.63157034}\times 10^{369693099}$ which finally gives: $4.281247546984804\dots \times10^{369693099}$

But this result is quite misleading. It is exactly what a calculator able of handling 64 bits floating point numbers will return, but the precision is far less what I initialy expected. The problem is that when computing $10^{.63157034}$, $0.63157034$ has only 5 or 6 decimal digits of precision, and not the 13 that a 64 bits floating point can carry. The reason is that the other bits of the mantissa are used for the integer part ($369693099)$, meaning here 29 bits.
So the last result should be written as: $4.28124\dots \times10^{369693099}$

If you want more decimals, please have a look at @Yves Daoust's excellent answer.

@YvesDaoust: I have finally understood the problem, explained it and added a link to your answer. If you think that it can still be misleading, I shall delete it (BTW what is WA?).
